# Hiding (only) text in TextView when clicked on TextView

Tags: android, textview

I want to only hide the text(string) written inside a TextView.

I don't mean to make the text transparent or making TextView invisible, because whenever I click on my screen(TextView), the text should disappear but the color of TextView should not change.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should elaborate a bit more, what you want to achieve with this and why the suggested methods do not work for you.

Comment: Trying to improve at least sentences to make it more readable and understandable, however, you should add some Code to explain more your problem and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting "" or " " as a text temporally?

```
textView.setText("");

textView.setText(" ");
```